# are cookies getting generated every time we visit website?

Tags: http, session, cookies

I am developing session management for our Web-server.  Below are steps I am following.

1. Very first time user comes to our server, We authenticate him based on username:password 
   provided and generate/set secure-cookie.
2. For subsequent request web-client will send same cookies back to us and we will validate
   it.
3. If cookie is valid then we serve the response. If cookie is invalid then we check 
   if authorization credentials are present and try to authenticate user and again
   generate/set secure-cookie
4. If cookie is not valid and no authorization credentials are present then send 401.

   With cookie we are also setting expiry time. This mainly for inactivity timeout.

   I want to know if I should regenerate cookie for subsequent request or not. 
   what will be a good design to generate or not to generate.

   If we don't generate then how we can keep user logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide sliding expiration. For example you define an idle timeout of 5 min, then when the user performs a request in the last two minutes, you deploy the same cookie with a extended expiration.

ASP.NET uses this technique.

Comment: we don't store cookie on server side or any other information related to cookie.  so in case if i need to extend expiration time then it is same as different cookie.  According to you i have to re-generate cookie for every subsequent request with new expiration time. Please clear this doubt.

Comment: The browser always send the cookie, so you parse it and if it is about to expire then you return a new cookie. The new cookie may be the same value with a new expiration date, as long your server can validate that the user didn't tamper the cookie.

Comment: My cookie contents are as below.

Comment: My cookie contents are as...    token = expiration_time:HMAC(expiration_time, "secret key")  so my cookie value will change if expiry time is changed. In my case i am thinking of having session cookie so i am not setting expiry time attribute of cookie. I need to regenerate cookie every time as i need to include new expiry time with cookie.

Comment: Right, regenerate the cookie each time then.